# Populating Listview / GridView on Universal Windows from a SQL Database C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview, gridview, win-universal-app

I have a database 'tbMenu' which displays the description and price of each meal and I want to know if its possible to populate this database on a listview or gridview for a phone application. What are the best options to go about this?

I have the phone application, a WCF Service( methods to call and return SQL queries) and the SQL server database.

I have searched online for similar questions but the answers were not specifically what I was looking for.

EDIT: What I am aiming for in the end is to have a listview in the app which displays "meals" and "price" taken from a SQL database. 
A multiple selection mode on the listview control will be used so all the selected items will calculate its total price.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the problem? There are several methods to accomplish what you're asking about. If you have an app, service and SQL then can you post the code? Is the code you have not working in some way?

Comment: I can't post the code at this time , I will edit the post when I can. I am simply stuck on a approach towards this and would like to know which options I have to go about this. List view / grid view on Windows Universal isn't the same as an ASP.net grid view for example where you can select the data source to display /edit. I am fairly new on phone apps so this is a practice session for me.

Comment: I have updated what I am aiming for if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think REST services are more common for phone apps due to lighter overhead than typical WCF services, but you might be able to create one with WCF. Retrieving the entire table in a single call doesn't seem like a good idea, so typically you'd want to implement [data virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt574120.aspx) to page in just the data you need using calls to your service.

Comment: I will read on this when I can , thanks! However first, populating the list/grid view first is the approach I am stuck on before implementing the data virtualisation . Selecting a data source on a grid view in asp.net as an example it's pretty straight forward, but in Windows universal it's not so much

Comment: Oh, then I'd start reading up on things from things like `ListView`, `ItemsSource`, `ItemTemplate` and `ObservableCollection`.